# Figure with 2 data in the same axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I need help to get a figure similar to the one I attached in the image. I do not get that each value is on its axis.

[image]

These are the values ​​with which I work.

```
    \addplot [black,fill] coordinates {
    (hasta 5,-13)
    (5.1 a 10,-14)
    (10.1 a 25,-10)
    (25.1 a 50,-5)
    (50.1 a 100,-5)
    (100.1 a 200,-3)
    (200.1 a 500,-13)
    (500.1 a 1000,-9)
    (1000.1 a 2500,-9)
    (2500.1 a 5000,-8)
    (5000.1 a 10000,-6)
    (más de 10000,-6)};
    \addlegendentry{EAPs};
    \addplot [black!30,fill] coordinates {
    (hasta 5,0)
    (5.1 a 10,0)
    (10.1 a 25,0.1)
    (25.1 a 50,0.1)
    (50.1 a 100,0.1)
    (100.1 a 200,0.2)
    (200.1 a 500,1.9)
    (500.1 a 1000,2.5)
    (1000.1 a 2500,5.8)
    (2500.1 a 5000,11.2)
    (5000.1 a 10000,16.1)
    (más de 10000,62)};
    \addlegendentry{Superficie};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are wondering why you are not receiving an answer very soon: generally questions with a compilable code, i.e. some code that starts with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` are answered much more timely. Yes, many know how to deal with symbolic coordinates and how to add a preamble, but why can't you add what you have and thus make it easier to write an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's old and there were no further replies from the TO.

Answer (score 2):

Few points to be noted here are that:

1. It would be better to give a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) explaining what you have tried and where you are stuck. It will save your as well as others time.
2. The x-coordinates in your data are not numbers. Hence they have to be defined as `symbolic`. Spaces in the x-coordinates can be handled with replacing them with '~'. Don't know if its the best way.
3. `xbar stacked` can be used to achieve this graph.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
xval        EAPs    Superficie  
hasta~5     -13 0
5.1~a~10    -14 0
10.1~a~25   -10 0.1
25.1~a~50   -5  0.1
50.1~a~100  -5  0.1
100.1~a~200 -3  0.2
200.1~a~500 -13 1.9
500.1~a~1000    -9  2.5
1000.1~a~2500   -9  5.8
2500.1~a~5000   -8  11.2
5000.1~a~10000  -6  16.1
m\`as~de~10000  -6  62
}\mytable
\begin{axis}[
xbar stacked,
stack negative=separate,
symbolic y coords={
hasta~5,
5.1~a~10,
10.1~a~25,
25.1~a~50,
50.1~a~100,
100.1~a~200,
200.1~a~500,
500.1~a~1000,
1000.1~a~2500,
2500.1~a~5000,
5000.1~a~10000,
m\`as~de~10000,
},
%
xmajorgrids,
ytick=data,
xmin=-20,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.2)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
]
\addplot[black,fill] table [x index=1,y=xval] {\mytable};
\addplot[black!30,fill] table [x index=2,y=xval] {\mytable};
\legend{EAPs,Superficie};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}}
```

[image]